# problems with bufferedRead and while loop

Tags: java, android

I have some problems with Android Java programming.

This is my situation:

- I am trying to load text lines from a text file.
- I will make every line as a separate string variable which will be
  saved in an `ArrayList`.
- I have no problems with running the application, but it fails when I
  press the button that will send a variable to method where the
  application will use to make every line as separate questions.
- The whole screen freezes after pressing the button on my phone.

I do not know how to fix this.

I am newbie in programming but I try my best, so any help is appreciated. Please ask if you did not understand or want more information, peace.

Here is the code:

```
public void levelOne(View v)throws IOException{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, pageBeforeAction.class);
    Button buttond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    createQuestions("hogskoleprovet.txt");
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void levelTwo(View v) throws IOException{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, pageBeforeAction.class);
    Button buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
    createQuestions("hogskoleprovet.txt");
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void createQuestions(String hogskoleprovet) throws IOException{
    InputStream iS = getResources().getAssets().open(hogskoleprovet);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iS));

    while(reader != null){
        String question = reader.readLine();
        String answer = reader.readLine();
        String answerOne = reader.readLine();
        String answerTwo = reader.readLine();
        String answerThree = reader.readLine();
        String answerFour = reader.readLine();  
        Question q = new Question (question, answer, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour);
        mQuestions.add(q);
        break;
    }
    reader.close();    
}
```

This is the output of my logcat:

```
 26837-26837/com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet, PID: 26837
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
```

Here is the xml-file (activity):

```
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@drawable/weather">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Var vänlig att tryck på den knappen för att välja vilket högskoleprov som du önskar spela. Tryck sedan Starta högskoleprovet, eller återvänd till menyn"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#ff171c45"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/line">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nivå 1"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg_knas"
        android:onClick="levelOne" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nivå 2"
        android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg_knas"
        android:onClick="levelTwo" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STARTA HÖGSKOLEPROVET"
        android:id="@id/buttonThree"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:onClick="startGame" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ÅTERVÄND TILL MENYN"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFour"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/redbutton_knas"
        android:onClick="returnMenu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi can I please see the XML design of your Activity for this?

Comment: This will not answer your question, but you should never do I/O (reading files for example) on the main thread. Use AsyncTask or Loader, ...

Comment: How should I do that? I am newbie

Comment: Well then my best advice is to start using search engines and google documentation and avoid damn youtube videos, they waste a lot of time http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Can it work if I still put as a main thread in the class? Because there are no other threads in that class

Comment: There is no such thing as 'a main thread in the class'.

Comment: should it work anyway on the main thread since this class will work in the background